# Convert flat csv for batch_importer

Tags: java, csv, neo4j, cypher, data-import

I'm trying to use the [Neo4j csv batch-importer](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14493611/batch_importer_20.zip) to upload a large csv (~20 mil lines). I'm stuck on how to parse the csv in order to use the importer. This is what the csv looks like:

```
CUSTOMER_NAME,TRANSACTION_DATE,TRANSACTION_NO,TRANSACTION_TYPE,COMPANY_TYPE,COMPANY_NAME,STREETNUM,STREETNAME,CITY,STATE,ZIPCODE
```

The graph structure is as follows -  I was creating the graph in the browser (too slow with this many lines):

```
MERGE (state:STATE{STATE: {line.STATE}})                  
MERGE (company:COMPANY{COMPANY_NAME: line.COMPANY_NAME, COMPANY_TYPE: line.COMPANY_TYPE, STREETNUM: line.STREETNUM, STREETNAME: line.STREETNAME}) 
MERGE (customer:CUSTOMER{CUSTOMER_NAME: line.CUSTOMER_NAME})                       
MERGE (zipcode:ZIPCODE{ZIPCODE: line.ZIPCODE})
MERGE (customer)-[:TRANSACTION{TRANSACTION_NO: line.TRANSACTION_NO, TRANSACTION_TYPE: line.TRANSACTION_TYPE}]->(company)-[:LOCATION]-(zipcode)
MERGE (state)-[:CITY{CITY: line.STATE}]-(zipcode)
```

How many csvs do I need to use with the [batch-importer](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14493611/batch_importer_20.zip)? Can I recreate this graph structure with just two csvs (nodes/rels)? If so, I'm confused about the structure of those particular csvs. For instance:

```
nodes.csv: 
COMPANY:string:COMPANY,l:label,COMPANY:string:COMPANY_NAME,COMPANY:string:COMPANY_TYPE,COMPANY:string:STREETNUM,COMPANY:string:STREETNAME
```

^where do I include the other nodes?

```
rels.csv
STATE:string:STATE,ZIPCODE:string:ZIPCODE,CITY,CITY:string:CITY
```

^how do I include a full path(2+ rels) or multiple relationships?

Answer (score 0):

The neo4j batch importer requires you to have the nodes and edges in separate csv files. 
I suggest you process your original file to generate the nodes.csv and edges.csv files with only the nodes and the edges in each file.

You can also specify multiple files for nodes and edges when using the importer, for example:
`import.bat test.db "nodes1.csv,nodes2.csv" "edges1.csv,edges2.csv"`

Hope that helps.

Comment: that's a step in the right direction. I can't get the properties of nodes to populate and it skips the creation of the relationships.